# Trying to send mail in C# but it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, email, smtp

So I wanted to try and send my self some mail using a Visual C# application but it seems to just run through the code (I know this because I put a message box at the end of the code) and not send anything. I did change the email information below for obvious reasons.

Here's what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Host = "smtp.live.com";
        Int16 Port = 587;
        bool SSL = true;
        string Username = "myemail@hotmail.com";
        string Password = "mypassword";

        // Mail options
        string To = "myemail@hotmail.com";
        string From = "email@hotmail.com";
        string Subject = "This is a test";
        string Body = "It works!";

        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(From, To, Subject, Body);
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient(Host, Port);
        NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
        sc.EnableSsl = SSL;
        sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        sc.Credentials = netCred;

        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
}
}
```

*Note, I get NO errors from this.

Comment: HINT: You set up all the information (host, from, to, subject, body), set the credentials, and all that looks fine. Where exactly do you actually **send** the mail? (Another hint: There should be more between `sc.Credentials = netCred;` and `MessageBox.Show("Test");`.)

Comment: Just realized I forgot to actually send the message. Now to figure this out.

Comment: Good. Got you started; now I can post an answer for when you come back. :)

Comment: @Hexo whats your issue? and how you solved it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually send the mail.

Add this to your code - you should be able to figure out where:

```
sc.Credentials = netCred;

try 
{
  sc.Send(message);
}  
catch (Exception ex) 
{
  MessageBox(ex.ToString());              
}              
MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

Comment: +1 but to match the OP's example, it should be `sc.Send(message);`

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help a lot (I got it to work, woohoo. Now to implement attachments :D)

I don't know why I was trying stmpclient though.

Answer (score -1):

Add these namespaces...

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
```

Add the following lines of code in Code-Behind file where you want to send an email.

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("yourEmailId", "destinationEmailId");
mail.Subject = ""; //Enter the text for the subject of the mail in quotes.
mail.Body = ""; //Enter the text for the body of mail within the quotes.
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("yourEmailId", "yourPassword");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = cred;
try
{
client.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of noise here that's not necessary. The OP had all the pertinent information except a single line of code (if you omit the `try..catch`. It's hard to read, because the extra noise makes the actual solution hard to find.